# Swagger not working properly with SB 3 + SpringDoc 2 when using GroupedOpenApi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

We have migrated a complex maven application (several modules many dependencies) from Spring Boot 2/javax to Spring Boot 3/jakarta. Therefore, we have migrated from using SpringDoc 1 to Springdoc 2.

In particular, the versions of the relevant packages that are being included in the final application are:

```
spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.4

springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0
springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.1.0
springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api:2.1.0

swagger-ui:4.18.2
swagger-core-jakarta:2.2.9
swagger-annotations-jakarta:2.2.9
swagger-models-jakarta:2.2.9
```

We use mostly java annotations to define the openapi/swagger.

We use custom end points for openapi and swagger documentation as:

```
# openapi documentation plus swagger
springdoc: 
  # openapi provides documentation in json format. Having it enabled is a requiment of swagger-ui
  api-docs:
    # URI. defaultValue=/v3/api-docs
    path: /api-docs
    # Enable / Disable springdoc-openapi enpoint
    enabled: true

  # swagger allows exercesicing the API from a browser
  swagger-ui:
    # URI. defaultValue=swagger-ui.html
    path: /docs
    # Enable / Disable the swagger-ui endpoint
    enabled: true
    # Sort endpoints alphabetically
    operationsSorter: method
    #Sort tags alphabetically
    tagsSorter: method
```

(This is the same as it used to be before the migration)

Swagger displays everything fine when we don't use `GroupedOpenApi` but when we add:

```
  private GroupedOpenApi getGroupedOpenApi(String category) {
    GroupedOpenApi group = GroupedOpenApi.builder().group(category).pathsToMatch(String.format("/%s/**",category)).build();
    log.info("Creating documentation group {} : {}", category, group.toString());
    return group;
  }

  @Bean public GroupedOpenApi c1OpenApi() { return getGroupedOpenApi("c1"); }
  @Bean public GroupedOpenApi c2OpenApi() { return getGroupedOpenApi("c2"); }
  @Bean public GroupedOpenApi c3OpenApi() { return getGroupedOpenApi("c3"); }
  @Bean public GroupedOpenApi c4OpenApi() { return getGroupedOpenApi("c4"); }
```

to our OpenApi configuration class the swagger endpoint shows:  `Could not render nn, see the console.` and
`No API definition provided.` but the yaml end point indeed has the correct values at `/api-docs/c1` `/api-docs/c2` etc.

To be clear, grouped api's specified with this same code were working on swagger just fine before the migration.

What could be the problem? The application itself is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't reproduce.
Can you provide a minimal repository to reproduce?

Comment: Currently I don't have anything minimal. One more experiment in case it helps: Defining the groups in the application properties by adding:

```
springdoc:
  group-configs:
    - group: c1
      paths-to-match: /c1/**
    - group: c2
      paths-to-match: /c2/**
    - group: c3
      paths-to-match: /c3/**
    - group: c4
      paths-to-match: /c4/**
```
instead of in Java (commenting out the java code) is completely ignored: Both `api-docs` and swagger-ui endpoints work fine with all end points in the same page (without any groups).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue myself and I'm not completely certain whether it's a bug or a known limitation.

What appears to be happening is that when you're creating a `GroupedOpenApi` bean within a configuration class (which is also a bean), it gets invoked very early during the configuration phase (at `SpringDocConfiguration`. At this point in time, many other bean creation processes, such as resolving values from property files, have not yet been executed. This means that a lot of configurations haven't been resolved at this stage.

When the creation process finally starts to execute, the configuration bean containing the `GroupedOpenApi` bean is already marked by Spring as having been loaded. Consequently, the process for resolving values skips over it. This leaves the bean at a very initial stage for the entire lifecycle of the application.

I managed to work around this by placing the `GroupedOpenApi` bean in a completely separate class without any other configuration, ensuring it doesn't depend on anything else. However, this solution might not be universally applicable and would need to be adjusted depending on the specific situation.